# Grafana Table Join by Multiple Fileds

Tags: prometheus, grafana

I use Grafana table visualization to display metrics stored in Prometheus. I got 4 PromQL queries to calculate the metric values.

All the metrics have labels `channel` and `currency`. Each of them has many but limited values and the queries are different aggregations by those 2 labels. I want the table to display values of channel and currency in the first 2 columns, and then display the results of the 4 PromQLs (marked as Value #A to Value #D) in the last 4 columns.

I setup the queries, changed their formats to table and then added the `Join By filed` transform. I use `Outer Join` mode. If I choose `channel` as the field to be joined, the table header becomes:

| channel | currency1 | Value #A | currency2 | Value #B | currency3 | Value #C | currency4 | Value #D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

What I actually want is:

| channel | currency | Value #A | Value #B | Value #C | Value #D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

But I can only select one field to join. And if I add more `Join by field` transformations, I got fields `currency1...4` to choose from, which doesn't look right.

I also tried `Merge` transform, but it then displays all the values in the time range as rows in the table, so I got many repeated rows for the same `channel` and `currency` values.

I wonder how can I configure the table panel to get my desired result?

EDIT: Queries ():

```
max_over_time( sum (increase(voucher_send_total{status=~"success"}[5m])) by(channel, currency) )[2d] // max historical value


sum (avg_over_time(voucher_backlog_total{})[5m]) by (channel, currency) 


300 / (avg by (channel, currency) (rate(voucher_requests_latency_seconds_sum{method=“/voucher/send"}[5m]) / rate(voucher_requests_latency_seconds_count{method=“/voucher/send"}[5m]))) * count by(channel, currency) (
 count by(channel, currency, id) (
  increase(voucher_wallets_total[24h]) > 0
 )
) // 5-minute theoretical max TPS

sum (increase(voucher_send_total{status=~"success"}[5m])) by(channel, curreny)
```

Format: Table, Type: Instant

Comment: Have you tried "merge" transformation?

Comment: @markalex Yes I have. But it doesn't work. I think it only works across multiple tables. I got error: Merge has no effect when applied on a single frame.

Comment: @markalex I actually found that `Organize fields` transform can hide/rename columns. It could serve as a temporary solution, though not a very descent one.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand something then. I thought you have 4 queries, each set to format *Table*, and *Instant*. Is that incorrect?

Comment: @markalex Yes, but they're all in one panel. I just added 4 queries in the same panel.

Comment: Yes, something like [this](https://play.grafana.org/d/_-yrsNGnk/table-panel-with-merge-transform-only-allows-first-data-type-37417?orgId=1&editPanel=3&tab=query&from=1693401950463&to=1693423550463) (but with 4 queries and prometheus as data source). Merge should work.

Comment: Oh yes. But merge does something else. It displays all the values in the time range as rows in the table. So there're so many repeated column values. Join by channel field generates distinct channels.

Comment: So you are not using query as *Instant*, but as *Range*?

Comment: I set the type in Options as Instant

Comment: Please add your queries to the question

Comment: In theory you can use `label_join` function to create new label, which will be combination of `channel` and `currency`. Then Grafana can use this new label for join in join transformation. You can hide that new label at the end with `Organize` transformation, because it is only to join results in Grafana.
Or you may use JOIN on the PromQL level https://ypereirareis.github.io/blog/2020/02/21/how-to-join-prometheus-metrics-by-label-with-promql/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is exactly fits description of [*Merge*](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#merge) transformation:

> Use this transformation to combine the result from multiple queries into one single result. This is helpful when using the table panel visualization. Values that can be merged are combined into the same row. Values are mergeable if the shared fields contain the same data.

Here is how it looks:
[image]

I've used four demo queries for this:

```
sum by (job, cluster) (up)
max by (job, cluster) (up + 4)
count by (job, cluster) ({job!=""})
sum by (job, cluster) ({job!=""})
```

all set to Format: *Table*, Type: *Instant*. And a single transformation *Merge*. It automatically detected rows with the same labels and times, and merged them into a single row.

To hide Time column you can additionally use *Organize fields* transformation.

Comment: If the time range is different in the PromQLs, can they still be merged?  I had different time ranges initially and got weird results. Not sure if it's related.

Comment: @JFreebird, I'm not sure, but I guess no. How you even managed to have different time ranges for queries within the same panel?

Comment: @JFreebird, if you want to simply ignore time while merging (your example table doesn't has column Time, and you said you use Type Instant ) you can use Transformation *Filter by name* before *Merge* to remove column Time from all your data sets.

Comment: Like metric1[range1] and metric2[range2]. And I have division and multiply operations on them also. Will it affect the result?

Comment: @JFreebird, oh in this case - it should not. These ranges are used inside aggregation functions, and are not affect time associated with result. Same for operations. If you still have problems with merge, please consider creation of [chat] room and posting step-by-step screenshoots of what you are doing. Because I created panel show in answer on play.grafana.com with no issues, and cannot grasp your problem.